# How to get the error in messge from the controller to the UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Ive MVC5 application and im using the following code to call to the action 
in the controller,and this is working fine.one thing that Im missing here is 
How should I trow the  message from the controller(like didnt able to save ).
How i send this error message to the ui?

I ask it becouse I use AJAX call to the action and not the regular way...

```
// Send data to the controller from the index view
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Users")',
        data: Data,
        success: successCreation,
        error: errorCreation,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

This is the controller method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public int Create(Users users)
        {
             try
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                     db.Users.Add(users);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {

                 throw new Exception("Test Exception");
             }


            return users.Id;
        }
```

Comment: well store that message in a model and pass model to view(UI) . have you ever tried like that

Comment: @supercool-no I dont ,can you please provide example?\

Comment: well ideally i can give you tips to work out . Still you face issue i will set up a sample :) create model with string properties then create a model instance and set the error messaged to that property and return model to view . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller Code :**

```
// POST: /HandlejQueryErrors/Contact/Create  
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Create(Users users)  
{  
    var response = new AjaxResponseViewModel();  

    try  
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 db.Users.Add(users);
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }
    }  
    catch (Exception exception)  
    {  
        response.Success = false;  
        response.Messages exception.Message;   
    }  

    return Json(response);  
}
```

**Add this to your Ajax request :**

```
 error: function ( xhr, errorType, exception ) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server  
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText  

            alert( "There was an error creating your contact: " + errorMessage );  
        }
```

For more help you can check this link : [Ajax Error Handler](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_errors.ashx).

Do let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: HI Krunal,Thanks but how should I do it in case of error can you please provide example in the context of post?since I not sure how to know if the ajax action failed and then take the message from the view bag or anything else and put it on the UI...

Comment: Hi Krunal,Thank you! but what is the AjaxResponseViewModel();  ?this is something that I need to build?if yes how it look like?

Comment: Just create a simple class like this for the AjaxResponseViewModel:
    public class AjaxResponseViewModel
    {
        public bool Success {get;set;}
        public string Message {get;set;}
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as is, the only thing to be added is your custom HandleErrorAttribute filter, so your controller code is separated from error handling (following separation of concerns:).

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            HandleErrorForAjax(filterContext); // return json-encoded error description
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext); //handle web requests as usual
        }
    }
```

So ultimately, your js code would receive 500 code and trigger 'error' handler.

(I wouldn't advise {success=false} approach as it returns 200 http code and breaks RESTful paradigm)